# how to stop a multiprocess in python

Tags: python, for-loop, process, multiprocessing, queue

When trying to run multiprocessing on a for loop all the process are being executed but the program is not terminated and keep running.

How can i stop the program after all elements in the list got processed?

```
def multiprocess_for_loop(*args, list_to_iter_over, function):
# the element in iterable is the first argument in the function
output = Queue()
processes = [Process(target=function, args=(elem,) + args) for elem in list_to_iter_over]
logging.info(f"start multiprocess for-loop on list: {list_to_iter_over}")
for p in processes:
    p.start()

results = []
for p in processes:
    results.append(output.get())

for p in processes:
    p.join()

logging.info("finished multiprocessing for-loop")
return results
```

Comment: The cleanest way is to make the process function return.

Comment: And BTW you are reading the output directly after starting. It might not be complete by then.

Comment: @KlausD. so when should i read the output? after the join?

Comment: How should I know? You did not show us the function.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- your code is not complete. And you must read the output of the queue *before* you join processes that are writing to it (see the documentation for `multiprocessing.Queue`).

Answer (score 0):

Every process write on Queue?
If a process don't write in it, your code keep stuck in that for.

Comment: can you elaborate on that?
how is it done?